# Laravel Build Eloquent Query to fetch data using fillters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my application i have product table with 4 different types of filters first step is user selects some filter from frontend then via ajax i push them into session and create a array of each type of filters..below is the code i wrote but it not working as i expected it only return results if there are no empty array passed in where clause but i want to fetch results whatever filter we pass in query

**filters array**

```
$industrytags = ['Agriculture & Farming','Medical'];
$styletags = ['Modern','Floral'];
$orientationtags = [];
$colortags = ['red','green'];
```

**Query**

```
$updatedproducts  = Product::whereIn('industry', $industrytags)->whereIn('style', $styletags)->whereIn('orientation', $orientationtags)->whereIn('color', $colortags)->get();
```

its not returning any results because now one of filter type is null but i want a query which fetches data with available filter

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$condition = "orientation IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') OR orientation IS NULL";

$updatedproducts  = Product::whereIn('industry', $industrytags)
->whereIn('style', $styletags)
->whereRaw($condition)
->whereIn('color', $colortags)->get();
```

Hope this will help you.